# How to append injectionMembers after registration in UnityContainer?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, interception

Suppose I have code like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IService, Implementation>(name, manager, 
    new InjectionConstructor(...));
```

Then I need to add InterceptionBehaviour to my registration, so it would be great if class ContainerRegistration have some method like `AppendInjectionMembers(...)`.

So the question is: is it possible to append injectionMembers after registration? And if so, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all, I found the answer

```
container.Configure<InjectedMembers>().
    ConfigureInjectionFor<Implementation>(new InterceptionBehavior());
```

Another way without using obsolete class `InjectedMembers`:

```
container.RegisterType(null, typeof(Implementation), new InterceptionBehavior());
```

Or even using generic version (thanks to Chris Tavares) :

```
container.RegisterType<Implementation>(new InterceptionBehavior());
```

Comment: You can leave off the initial null, and use generics: container.RegisterType<Implementation>(new InterceptionBehavior());  InjectionMembers are additive; if you configure the same thing (multiple InjectionFactory for example) then last one configured wins.

Comment: Can you register multiple behaviors this way? Like: 
`container.RegisterType<Implementation>(new FirstInterceptionBehavior()); 
container.RegisterType<Implementation>(new SecondInterceptionBehavior());`